# How to use General Energy Equation in parallel pipes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

My question comes from exercises with parallel pipes such as this.

[image]
I know that to analyse internal flow, we use general energy equation which origins from the 1st law so each time we apply it we are using a Control Volume. However for this type of question, if I apply a CV that goes from 1 to 2, part of the mass flows toward C and so starting from the 1st law the equation should become like this:

[image]
[image]

[image]

However the solution tells me that it is:

[image]

I dont understand why you can procede as the solution. It ignores the mass flow toward 3, almost as if there is only mass flow from 1 to 2 which permits it to cancel out completely the mass flow.

EDIT: Equations from 1 to J and from J to 2.  The velocity heads still remains. Have I done anything wrong?
[image]

Comment: There is pressure drop in the piping and in the valve going to tank 3 that is not accounted for in your Bernoulli equation approach.

Comment: Yeah i didnt account for that because my CV only goes from 1 to 2.   My confusion is basically that the solution treats the energy equation as if it is bernoulli by following the same streamline. But we take a CV, no matter how,for example from 1 to 2 or 
the covering the whole fluid, it is inevitable to consider the energy that carries the mass in 3, which isnt in the solution.

Comment: Questions: 1) Are the levels in the 3 tanks constant?  2) Are you open to a somewhat different approach to solving this problem?  3) Do you have a way to estimate pressure drop in piping and the valve as a function of flow rate?  4) Are there elevation differences between the tanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term involving $V_B$ takes into account the fact that it doesn't involve the full flow.  You also need to include the continuity equation which helps to establish the flow rate split between branches B and C.  Also, the pressure at junction J has to be the same for the entrance to branches B and C, and this too helps to constrain the split.

Comment: The term that you are referring is f(L/d)Vb^2/g right?  So does it mean that we are just considering the flow rate of B along the way from 1 to 2?  If that is the case how can we still consider the head loss through branch A with the velocity of A?

Comment: No. The frictional term from 1 to J includes the total flow (the sum of the flows in B and C).  The frictional term from J to 2 includes only the flow in B.  Write the equations for 1 to J, J to 2, and J to 3 separately and see what you get.

Comment: I have updated my post. Could you check it?

Comment: It looks OK to me.

Comment: I did disregard them both. From 1 to J V1 is 0 but Velocity in J is Va.   From J to 2, the velocity in J is Vb. If I have considered it to be Va, that would mean my CV will be before the junction, and so I would need to consider energy of the mass that leaves toward 3.

Comment: Oops.  I just noticed that there is going to be a jump in pressure between duct A and duct B at junction J.  This jump will be equal to the change in KE between the two duct flows.  So the KE terms are going to cancel out (in agreement with their result).